# Python Type hinting, two different approaches?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I am currently trying to understand type hinting in Python. I try to understand the difference between these two lines:
`var1 = List[str]` and `var1: List[str] = []`.

Can someone explain to me what the first one does? When I read the documentation of type hinting I got the impression that it's basically the same.

Problem was, that when I did use the first line, when I tried to use `.append(...)` on it, I got a TypeError, saying that I cannot use append() on a str object.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: The first line is used to declare a custom type-hint. The second one is just a use of type-hint. This is very useful when you use linting (pylint etc) or work with an IDE. It helps you identify the possible mistakes, for instance when you try to append an integer to a `List[str]` list. You will receive a warning from the linter and/or the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

`var1 = List[str]` is not the same as `var1: List[str] = []`
With `var1 = List[str]` you are making var1 a hint type, a better example would be:

```py
    MyListOfStr = List[str]
    var1: MyListOfStr = []
```